Azure DevOps Pipeline Fails During Package Publishing Step for .NET 8 Project
I have a .Net 8 Project running in an Azure Function App and I am using via Azure devops pipeline as CICD. Everything runs fine without issue. Now I am having some problems. I have not made a code change. I am only adding a postman test to be included via Azure devops pipeline. However the pipeline jobs fails on publishing package step. Before ever getting to postman testing, so I know for sure, it has nothing to do with my change.
Here is the error:
Publish Package

View raw log

Starting: Publish Package
==============================================================================
Task         : .NET Core
Description  : Build, test, package, or publish a dotnet application, or run a custom dotnet command
Version      : 2.238.1
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli
==============================================================================
Info: .NET Core SDK/runtime 2.2 and 3.0 are now End of Life(EOL) and have been removed from all hosted agents. If you're using these SDK/runtimes on hosted agents, kindly upgrade to newer versions which are not EOL, or else use UseDotNet task to install the required version.
/opt/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/dotnet publish /home/vsts/work/1/s/Functions/Functions.csproj --no-restore --configuration Release --output /home/vsts/work/1/App -p:version=1.0.1-DEVS-101_PostmanTest
MSBuild version 17.9.8+b34f75857 for .NET
  Copying IronPdf files from /home/vsts/.nuget/packages/ironpdf.native.chrome.windows/2024.1.143/buildTransitive/netstandard2.0/../../runtimes to build directory for target framework net8.0 on Windows...
/opt/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/sdk/8.0.204/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.GenerateAssemblyInfo.targets(226,5): error NETSDK1018: Invalid NuGet version string: '1.0.1-DEVS-101_PostmanTest'. [/home/vsts/work/1/s/Functions/Functions.csproj]

##[error]Error: The process '/opt/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/dotnet' failed with exit code 1
##[warning].NET 5 has some compatibility issues with older Nuget versions(<=5.7), so if you are using an older Nuget version(and not dotnet cli) to restore, then the dotnet cli commands (e.g. dotnet build) which rely on such restored packages might fail. To mitigate such error, you can either: (1) - Use dotnet cli to restore, (2) - Use Nuget version 5.8 to restore, (3) - Use global.json using an older sdk version(<=3) to build
Info: Azure Pipelines hosted agents have been updated and now contain .Net 5.x SDK/Runtime along with the older .Net Core version which are currently lts. Unless you have locked down a SDK version for your project(s), 5.x SDK might be picked up which might have breaking behavior as compared to previous versions. You can learn more about the breaking changes here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/ and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/ . To learn about more such changes and troubleshoot, refer here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops#troubleshooting
##[error]Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects : [
  '/home/vsts/work/1/s/Functions/Functions.csproj'
]
Finishing: Publish Package

Here is the pipeline task it fails on:
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      name: Publish_Package
      displayName: Publish Package
      inputs:
        command: publish
        publishWebProjects: false
        projects: $(Project)
        arguments: --no-restore --configuration Release --output $(Pipeline.Workspace)/App -p:version=$(Build.BuildNumber)
        modifyOutputPath: false

Any pointers to what might be wrong will be helpful.

The underscores _ character in branchname is not allowed in Semantic Versioning.

error NETSDK1018: Invalid NuGet version string: '1.0.1-DEVS-101_PostmanTest'

From the task, this string is added from the azure pipeline Build.BuildNumber variable -p:version=$(Build.BuildNumber)
The branchname is included as part of BuildNumber variable of Azure pipeline. See what is included in Build.BuildNumber
Renaming the name of your branch name from DEVS-101_PostmanTest to DEVS-101-PostmanTest to have a valid version string that follows Semantic Versioning rules, should resolve this issue.

I changed the branch name and got it running fine again, but I dont want this to reoccured in the future . How can I make change to the build number format in the pipeline settings to bypass this issue even if the branch name has this underscores.
> See what is included in Build.BuildNumber
My pipeline has this defined:
name: $(major).$(minor).$(patch)-${{ variables['Build.SourceBranchName'] }}

You can pass a function to the Build.SourceBranchName variable to removes _ character and replace with hyphens -.  Preferably as a variable say.
branch: $[ replace(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], '_', '-') ]
Then use this sanitized branchname to define your Build.BuildNumber
name: $(major).$(minor).$(patch)-$(branch)
An another alternative is to remove the branch name from the Build.SourceBranchName entirely, if its not relevant for you.
name: $(major).$(minor).$(patch)

Copied and reused your branch variable at my end and it worked fine.


/opt/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/sdk/8.0.204/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.GenerateAssemblyInfo.targets(226,5): error NETSDK1018: Invalid NuGet version string: '1.0.1-DEVS-101_PostmanTest'

Test to run the dotnet publish with the same version format: 1.0.1-DEVS-101_PostmanTest, I can reproduce the same issue.

The cause of the issue is that the version format is not meet the Semantic Versioning 2.0.0 standard. You need to avoid using the  character: _ in the version suffix
Related argument in dotnet publish task:  -p:version=$(Build.BuildNumber)
To solve this issue, you can  modify the variable $(Build.BuildNumber) to use the following format:
From:
1.0.1-DEVS-101_PostmanTest

To
1.0.1-DEVS-101.PostmanTest

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: Package versioning
